# Компилятор не видит файл "wnspool.lib"

Tags: visual-c++, sfml

Хотел написать игру на C++ с помощью SFML. 
Библиотеки все есть:
**sfml-graphics-d.lib;sfml-window-d.lib;sfml-system-d.lib;sfml-audio-d.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)**
Конфигурация: **Debug**
Путь к библиотекам и включаемых файлов настроен
**!!!**: файл "*wnspool.lib*" есть в дополнительных зависимостях, также, как и библиотеки для SFML
Мне компилятор выдал ошибку:

```
Сборка начата…
1>------ Сборка начата: проект: FIrstISFML, Конфигурация: Debug Win32 ------
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: не удается открыть файл "wnspool.lib"
1>Сборка проекта "Project1.vcxproj" завершена с ошибкой.
========== Сборка: успешно: 0, с ошибками: 1, без изменений: 0, пропущено: 0 ==========
```

Я пробовал менять конфигурацию, вставлять DLL-файлы в папку проекта, а также в папку *Debug* и *Release*, убирать какие-либо файлы с расширением .lib в дополнительных зависимостях
Я взял код с оф. сайта для проверки:

```
    #include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
    using namespace sf;

    int main()
    {
        RenderWindow window(VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
        CircleShape shape(100.f);
        shape.setFillColor(Color::Green);

        while (window.isOpen())
        {
            Event event;
            while (window.pollEvent(event))
            {
                if (event.type == Event::Closed)
                    window.close();
            }

            window.clear();
            window.draw(shape);
            window.display();
        }

        return 0;
}
```

И он не создаёт:
[image: Окно показывает, что SFML работает]

Comment: lib- файлы бывают разных версий. Нужно искать lib именно для вашей среды.

Comment: Это похоже на опечатку в `Winspool.lib`

Comment: @user7860670, Нет, именно wnspool.lib

Comment: ¿А что делает эта библиотека и где вы ее раздобыли?

Comment: @user7860670 Я не знаю, но она уже лежала в дополнительных зависимостях проекта (Linker/Input), но, почему-то, компилятор думает что такого файла нет

Comment: попробуй закинуть его в System32